# Recursive Directory search, Showing most recent file in folder

Tags: find, cut, stat, head

Can someone point out where am going wrong please. 
Am doing a directory search (Based on the folder structure and file type) 
The folder structure is the same for every customer.
Just the customer folder is named differently. 
Example of structure:

- Httpdocs/client1/channel1/backup
- Httpdocs/client5/channel5/backup
- Httpdocs/client8/channel1/backup

This partially works, It just shows me ALL files in the backup folder
apposed to the most recent file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of root folders
#folders=("a" "b")
array=(httpdocs/*\/client1/backup/*.xml)

# Search all specified root folders
for dir in "${array[@]}"; 
do echo "$dir";
    # date of each file with "stat"
    find -path $array -type f -exec stat -f "%m,%N" {} ';' | \
        # sort by date, most recent first
        sort -gr | \
        # extract first (most recent) file
        head -1 | \
        # return file name only
        cut -d, -f2
done
```

head appears to not be working. Any reason why? is my formatting wrong?

i also tried:

```
find -path "*\/chanel1/backup/*.xml" -type f | sort -gr | head -1 | cut -d, -f2
```

This just outputs the Last folder in the list with the latest file in that folder. (I have to run this within Web Root (Httpdocs))

Comment: I was able to get this working with the following     `find -path "*/chanel1/backup/*.xml" -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head'` But there is some folders missing in the list.

Comment: Something like `find -type f -path "*/chanel1/backup/*.xml"  -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -nr | head -n 1 |  cut -d ' ' -f2-`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something more like your last approach, such as

`for d in $(find httpdocs -type d -name backup)
do   ls -t $d | grep '.xml$' | head -1
done`

`ls -t` sorts by modified time, most recent first.

If you want the full pathname in the output, you can use `ls -t $d/*.xml` and skip the grep.  There are simple but non-obvious ways to shorten the pathname if you wish, like sed or dirname.